# How to add new section below shipping method and above next button on checkout page - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I searched for the reference URL from that I can able to add above the "Shipping Method" or below "Next".

But Not able to add the text box between "Shipping Method" and "Next" button section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[How To In Magento 2 – How To Display Additional Text Based On Selected Shipping Methods In The Checkout](https://zanetabaran.com/how-to-in-magento-2-how-to-display-additional-text-based-on-selected-shipping-methods-in-the-checkout/)

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="shipping-info-wrapper" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-info</item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```